# SQL statements from several tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Given the following two tables:

```
Users table 
id (pk) 
name
avatar 

Comments table 
id (pk) 
id_pic (fk)
id_user (fk)
text 
date
```

How do I create an SQL statement that returns all information for Pics with id=7?

Important: I want information from the Comment (id, text, date) and from the user that has written the comment (id, name, avatar)

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried this, but it returns me 1 row, when it would have to be 2:

```
SELECT c.id, c.id_user, u.avatar, u.name, c.date, c.text 
FROM Comments c 
INNER JOIN Users u 
ON u.id=c.id_user AND c.id_pic=7;
```

**Edit 2:**
Some data:

```
Users
id   name   avatar
1    joe    true
2    lee    false

Comments
id   id_pic   id_user  text         date
1    7        2        cool         2018-09-09
2    7        1        great        2018-09-10
3    10       1        ugly         2018-09-10
```

**Edit 3:**
It works ok when I do this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.id_user, c.date, c.text 
FROM Comments c 
INNER JOIN Users u
ON u.id=c.id_user AND c.id_pic=7;
```

But it doesn't show in the rows the info that I need (u.avatar and u.name) :(

Comment: Show us some sample data as well.....

Comment: Your query runs fine for me and returns 2 rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ede5/1

Comment: Your query is correct, it should return 2 records. try it again!

Comment: You use select *. I don't want to use that

Comment: @Ommadawn, the query you posted is that complete statement you are running  or do you have more to it? The query posted as is will return correct data.

Comment: Sorry guys, my data base is huge and has a lot of more columns... I tried to simplify all the stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query worked for me.  If you want to get the avatar and name, you have to include it in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT c.id, c.id_user, c.date, c.text, u.avatar, u.name 
FROM dbo.comments c
INNER JOIN dbo.users u ON u.id = c.id_user
WHERE c.id_pic = 7
```

Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: this query is no different than what he posted. They both will return same value.